# Annihilation of two-particles intermediate states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, identical-particles

I'm doing time-independent perturbation theory at the fourth order to calculate dispersion energy of two-polarizable neutral atoms in their ground state and in the electromagnetic field vacuum, to derive Casimir-Polder force. In the sum between intermediate states, this term appears
\begin{gather*}
\sum\limits_{\lambda\mu} \iint \text{d}^3 k\, \text{d}^3 l\,
\left(
\sum\limits_\nu \int \text{d}^3 m\,
\langle 1_{\boldsymbol{k}\lambda} | \hat{a}_{\boldsymbol{m}\nu} | 1_{\boldsymbol{k}\lambda},1_{\boldsymbol{l}\mu} \rangle
\right)
\end{gather*}
but seems to me no easy task to calculate it: in fact may be the situation in which $(\boldsymbol{l},\mu)=(\boldsymbol{k},\lambda)$, and, with equal indices should be $\hat{a}|2\rangle=\sqrt{2}|1\rangle$. I expect to obtain something like
\begin{gather*}
\sum\limits_{\lambda\mu} \iint \text{d}^3 k\, \text{d}^3 l\,
\left(
( 1 - \delta(\boldsymbol{l}-\boldsymbol{k}) \delta_{\mu\lambda} )
\langle 1_{\boldsymbol{k}\lambda} | 1_{\boldsymbol{k}\lambda} \rangle
+ 
\sqrt{2} \delta(\boldsymbol{l}-\boldsymbol{k}) \delta_{\mu\lambda}
\langle 1_{\boldsymbol{k}\lambda} | 1_{\boldsymbol{k}\lambda} \rangle
\right)
\end{gather*}
to differentiate between the distinguishable and indistinguishable cases, but it's far from systematic, and, having never encountered this situation, I'm not convinced by this.

How can I deal with two-particle states, passing continously from the distinguishable to the non-distinguishable case, under an integration, and what is the right way to proceed in this calculation?